# Return JSON data only if specific key exist

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to parse through a JSON file and return results only if specific key exists.  Here is the example of the JSON:

```
"phone_numbers": [
        {
            "id": "123456",
            "number": "+11234567890",
            "source": "external",
            "status": "available",
            "number_type": "toll",
            "capability": [
                "incoming",
                "outgoing"
            ],
            "location": "United States",
            "assignee": {
                "id": "1234",
                "name": "John Smith",
                "extension_number": 7890,
                "type": "user"
            },
            "site": {
                "id": "123456",
                "name": "COPQ"
            },
            "emergency_address": {
                "country": "US",
                "address_line1": "Testing",
                "address_line2": "Testing",
                "city": "Testing",
                "state_code": "PA",
                "zip": "19428"
            },
            "emergency_address_status": 1
        },
```

So for above I only want to return record if key 'assignee' is present, if not just bypass it.  For now I'm just trying to count how many records have 'assignee' but can't get it to work.  Here is what I'm using:

```
counter = 0

for i in user_data['phone_numbers']:
    if i['assignee']:
        counter += 1

print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` keyword. The `in` keyword can also be used to check if a value is present in a sequence.
For example,

```py
colors = ["red", "blue", "green"]
print("red" in colors) # True
```

The solution of your problem is as below-

```py
records = []
for d in user_data["phone_numbers"]:
    if "assignee" in d:
        records.append(d)
print(len(records))
```

Comment: Dictionaries by default support set operations such as `if "assignee" in d` thus no need for `d.keys()`. You would only need to use `d.keys()` in python2

Comment: You didn't need `d.keys()` in Python 2, either. A `dict` has always behaved as an iterable of its keys. (In Python 2, the `keys` method returned a list of the keys, independent of future changes to the `dict`. In Python 3, it returns a specialized set-like iterable of type `dict_keys`.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the d.keys() portion

Answer (score 0):

> trying to count how many records have 'assignee'

You can use a generator expression to get that count

```
sum(1 for p in data["phone_numbers"] if "assignee" in p)
```

To get a list of all numbers with assignee keys, then a list-comprehension

```
assignees = [p in data["phone_numbers"] if "assignee" in p]
```